# How to run a script or command every time a terminal (zsh) opens in a VSCode workspace?

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, terminal, zsh

I am working on a Django project on macOS. My terminal runs zsh.

I want to create helpful aliases, like `run` instead of `python manage.py runserver`, but, I don't want to run these commands every single time I open a new terminal.

So here's what's going on:

- I don't want to create these aliases or run any command in my home directory's `.zshrc` or `.zprofile` because I don't want them to be system-wide. **I want to run them on local project directories exclusively.**
- Every time we open a new terminal on VSCode, when working with a selected Python virtual environment, a command to activate it gets run first thing. It will look like this:

  ```
    source /Users/.../venv/bin/activate
  ```

  This (should be) carried out by Microsoft's Python extension. I cloned its repo but had no luck finding **where they place this in VSCode's configurations**. Where do they?
- Some posts on StackOverflow told me to take a look on the `terminal.integrated.profiles.osx` setting. I did, and the closest thing I came to was creating this profile:

  ```
    "zsh (Django)": {
        "path": "zsh",
        "args": [
            "-c", "source setup.sh"
        ]
    }
  ```

  `setup.sh` is a file on my working directory. Its only command, for now, is `echo "Hello World"`.

  I also tried to include only `"setup.sh"` in args.

  Always had the same result: terminal opens, sources `venv/bin/activate`, prints "Hello World" and quits right after. (Why?!) Here is a GIF of what happens: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChK62.jpg

In summary: I want to run commands once terminal gets opened, just like `source` gets run automatically, and I have no idea how to pull this off.

Comment: Maybe it's worth thinking in that way: Do you really want it **only** in terminals opened from within VSCode, or from **every** interactive zsh shell you are creating? In the latter case, I wouldn't care much what VSCode is doing, but just putting the required setup code inside your `.zshrc`.

Answer (score 1):

vscode sets environment variables. So if you check for one of these variables from `.zshrc` or similar, you can make the change in a manner that is not system-wide. For example:

```
    if [[ $TERM_PROGRAM = vscode ]]; then
      source /Users/.../venv/bin/activate
      …
    fi
```